# yaml format by default in springdoc

Tags: java, spring, rest, openapi, springdoc

Using springdoc is it possibile to have swagger link the api documentation in yaml format by default?

By default springdoc have swagger link the api documentation in json format. Sometimes it's desirable to have the documentation in yaml format by default.

Answer (score 0):

By default springdoc serves the api documentation

at /v3/api-docs in json format
at /v3/api-docs.yaml in yaml format

The first is shown to as a link in swagger-ui. To have the second shown as link you need to set the following spring configuration property

springdoc.swagger-ui.url: /v3/api-docs.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to have Swagger link the API documentation in YAML format by default when using Springdoc.

Springdoc integrates with Swagger UI to generate API documentation, and Swagger UI supports both JSON and YAML formats. To configure Springdoc to use YAML as the default format, you can follow these steps:

Include the necessary dependencies: Make sure you have the required dependencies in your project. You need springdoc-openapi-ui for Swagger UI integration and snakeyaml for YAML support.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Configure Springdoc to use YAML format: In your Spring Boot application configuration, you can define a bean of type OpenAPI and configure it to produce YAML output. You can use the YamlOpenAPIResource class provided by Springdoc to generate the YAML documentation.

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import org.springdoc.core.SwaggerUiConfigParameters;
import org.springdoc.core.SwaggerUiConfigParametersBuilder;
import org.springdoc.core.SwaggerUiConfigProperties;

@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI openAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI();
    }

    @Bean
    public SwaggerUiConfigParameters swaggerUiConfigParameters() {
        SwaggerUiConfigProperties properties = new SwaggerUiConfigProperties();
        properties.setConfigUrl("/v3/api-docs.yaml"); // Set the YAML URL as the default

        return new SwaggerUiConfigParametersBuilder(properties).build();
    }
}
```

In this configuration, setConfigUrl() is used to set the default URL for the Swagger UI configuration. By setting it to "/v3/api-docs.yaml", it tells Swagger UI to load the documentation in YAML format by default.

Generate and access the YAML documentation: Start your application, and you can access the API documentation in YAML format by navigating to the following URL:

bash

```
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/v3/api-docs.yaml
```

This URL will load Swagger UI with the API documentation in YAML format.

Note: The configUrl parameter is used to specify the URL of the Swagger configuration file. In this case, it points to the YAML file generated by Springdoc.